# Fitting a wxWindows frame to a grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

In my *wxPython* GUI app I want to show a dialog with a grid on it and just two buttons below that grid. The grid may be initialised with a number of rows, which is not known in advance. My goal is to automatically let the dialog window become as large as necessary in order to include the whole grid (i.e. I would like to avoid the scrollbars of the grid).

However, I can't get that to work, even when using sizers and the `wx.EXPAND` flag. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? This is a fully working example of my problem:

```py
import wx
import wx.grid

class MyApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(None, title="wxPython Sizers", style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Keras model to product / pipe type mapping grid
        logtab = wx.grid.Grid(self.panel)
        logtab.CreateGrid(25, 3)
        logtab.SetColLabelValue(0, "One")
        logtab.SetColLabelValue(1, "Two")
        logtab.SetColLabelValue(2, "Three")
        grid_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer.Add(logtab, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(grid_sizer)

        # Dialog buttons
        btns = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        save_button = wx.Button(self, label="Save")
        cancel_button = wx.Button(self, label="Cancel")
        btns.Add(save_button)
        btns.Add(cancel_button)

        # Set final dialog layout
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.panel, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=15)
        self.main_sizer.Add(btns, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=15)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.main_sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wxapp = wx.App()
    myApp = MyApp()
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You're using an `id` instead of a proportion value, when adding to `grid_sizer`. Use `grid_sizer.Add(logtab, proportion=1, flag = wx.EXPAND)` instead.

Comment: Ohh great, that's it. If you post this as answer I will happily accept it :)

Comment: No point really. It's an oversight that just needed an extra pair of eyes. These sneaky little beggars cause grief for us all.